# iOS NSPredicate Contains from an index

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, nspredicate, contains

I have a `NSArray` like this: `"test01_asdf","test01_efgh","test02_ghjk"`.
I need to filter those items using `NSPredicate` Contains, but I have to limit the filtering action range to all the characters after the 7th one.
I mean: forget about the "testNN_" part, use the contains filter only for the rest of the strings ("asdf","efgh","ghjk").
So if the searching text is "e", it would return only "test01_efgh" and not all the items, since they all contains the "e" in the word "test".
I'm a black box that receives this input and have to give that output.

By now I have this line:

```
NSPredicate *predicateFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", [myfilterstring lowercaseString]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MATCHES` instead of `CONTAINS`.

```
NSArray *a = @[ @"test_abc", @"test_def" ];

NSString *search = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*_.*%@.*", @"c"];

NSLog(@"%@", [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", search]]);
```

The above code prints: test_abc

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I've added the "[cd]" for the insensitive casing and diacritics characters ("SELF MATCHES[cd] %@").

Answer (score 1):

construct another array that has these elements chopped using **substring**, do the manipulation you want on it, and make use of it's ids or element number to use in the original array, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are a block box, and just need to provide the output, I'm not sure why you want to use NSPredicate. There are any number of more convenient ways to solve this problem without NSPredicate.

But since NSPredicate can take an arbitrary test block, you can write a predicate that solves this problem; you aren't restricted to the built in language:

```
import Foundation

func filterArray(array: [String]) -> [String] {
    let predicate = NSPredicate { (value, _) -> Bool in
        let string = value as! NSString
        if string.length > 7 {
            return string.substringFromIndex(7).containsString("e")
        }
        return false
    }

    var matches: [String] = []
    for value in array {
        if predicate.evaluateWithObject(value) {
            matches.append(value)
        }
    }
    return matches
}

let array = ["test01_asdf","test01_efgh","test02_ghjk"]
print(filterArray(array))
```